# Higher Voltage = Improved Signal Strength

Tags: switches, signal, pullup, reed-switch

I'm using a reed switch to detect the state of my garage door. It's connected to an ESP8266 via twisted cables of 1.5m and each line has a pull-up as the signal floats too much otherwise.

Well it still floats and I've been wondering whether it would've been wiser to use the 5V for the pull-up instead of the 3.3V I used. The ESP is 5V-tolerant so that should be no problem.

As far as I know, the higher the voltage the stronger the signal, but I may be spoiled by landlines with high voltage. :-)

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Adding a diagram of your existing design would help. However assuming you have your pull-up (currently to 3.3V) on the input pin to read "High" when the reed switch is *open*, and expect to read "Low" when the reed switch *closes* and connects the signal to Gnd, then in which state(s) do you believe the signal still "floats"? How did you decide that it floats - did you view that signal with an oscilloscope? What value is your pull-up resistor? Only a 1.5m cable is very short to be having problems...

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFFO9t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Filter capacitor on input.*

Try adding a 100 nF capacitor on the input to your micro. This will shunt any high-frequency noise to ground and provide a little "debounce". The small delay when the switch opens - a couple of milliseconds - should not delay you getting the car in and out of the garage.